# Hide table rows if the checkbox is checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, hide

I've got 5 checkboxes for the status row of my table. In my status row I've got the number of the status. My problem is to show if status 1 or status 4 or status 7, etc..., is checked, to show or hide the table row.

**Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ChristianCo/dg04m8xy/**

```
function AA_Status_Durchsuchen() {
    // Declare variables
    var status1, status4, status7, status8, status9, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    status1 = document.getElementById("statuserstellt").checked;
    status4 = document.getElementById("statusgesperrt").checked;
    status7 = document.getElementById("statuszurfreigabe").checked;
    status8 = document.getElementById("statusrejected").checked;
    status9 = document.getElementById("statusfreigegeben").checked;
    table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    if (status1 == true) {
        status1 = 1;
    } else {
        status1 = null;
    }
    if (status4 == true) {
        status4 = 4;
    } else {
        status4 = null;
    }

    if (status7 == true) {
        status7 = 7;
    } else {
        status7 = null;
    }
    if (status8 == true) {
        status8 = 8;
    } else {
        status8 = null;
    }
    if (status9 == true) {
        status9 = 9;
    } else {
        status9 = null;
    }

    //console.log(status1, status4, status7, status8, status9);

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
      if (td) {
        // <- - - - - here I need your help!
        if (status1.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. Can you create an example in https://jsfiddle.net/ and update your comment with a link to it? That would make it easier to understand

Comment: the filter variable is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

You could do this based on the index of the dom elements of your tr and input elements:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach(cb => {
  // initial values
  const index = [...cb.parentElement.children].indexOf(cb);
  document.querySelector(`table tr:nth-child(${index + 1})`).style.display = "none";
})

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(cb => {
  cb.addEventListener('change', e => {

    const index = [...e.currentTarget.parentElement.children].indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    const checked = e.currentTarget.checked

    if (checked) {
      document.querySelector(`table tr:nth-child(${index + 1})`).style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.querySelector(`table tr:nth-child(${index + 1})`).style.display = "";
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rttmax/wcony583/36/

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it works for me.

```
function AA_Status_Durchsuchen() {
// Declare variables
var status1, status4, status7, status8, status9, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
status1 = document.getElementById("statuserstellt").checked;
status4 = document.getElementById("statusgesperrt").checked;
status7 = document.getElementById("statuszurfreigabe").checked;
status8 = document.getElementById("statusrejected").checked;
status9 = document.getElementById("statusfreigegeben").checked;
table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

if (status1 == true) {
    status1 = "1";
} else {
    status1 = null;
}
if (status4 == true) {
    status4 = "4";
} else {
    status4 = null;
}

if (status7 == true) {
    status7 = "7";
} else {
    status7 = null;
}
if (status8 == true) {
    status8 = "8";
} else {
    status8 = null;
}
if (status9 == true) {
    status9 = "9";
} else {
    status9 = null;
}

//console.log(status1, status4, status7, status8, status9);

filter = (status1 || status4 || status7 || status8 || status9);


// Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];

  if (td) {

    //
    if (filter > -1) {
        if (td.textContent == status1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else if (td.textContent == status4) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else if (td.textContent == status7) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else if (td.textContent == status8) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else if (td.textContent == status9) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
  };
}
```

}
}